# Getting an information from the model that is related using ForeignKey in Django

Tags: django

I am still getting the hang of Django. For example, you have two models and one of them is related to the other using ForeignKey.

```
class Parent(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   birthday= models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)

class Child(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   parent= models.ForeignKey(Parent)
```

In the example above, i would like to access the particular child and get his name. I will like to do it through the parent instance. So for example, i have a Parent called John and i would like to know his child's name. How do i do it?

Please pardon me if it is a simple question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below code addresses your question. Note that `child_set` is the related manager's default name. For more information, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/

```
john = Parent.objects.get(name='John')
johns_children = john.child_set.all()
# Print names of his children
for child in johns_children:
    print child.name
# Get child named Jack
jack = john.child_set.get(name='jack')
# Filter children by gender
jack = john.child_set.filter(gender='F')
...
```

Comment: lets take the case where there is one child instead of many, then i can access it john.child.name... Am i right?

Comment: can you use (related name) to solve the answer?like parent=models.ForeignKey(Parent,related_name=child).. then accessing the child's name by typing john.child.name? is this correct?

Comment: Foreign key relationship associates a parent object with multiple child objects. If you don't need multiple objects, use a one-to-one relationship instead. If you need the flexibility of a one-to-many relationship, then you can use get or filter methods of the related manager to fetch the object you want.

Answer (score 1):

Given a parent object `parent = Parent.objects.get(name='John')`, you can get his children by using `children = Child.objects.filter(parent=parent_id)`, then it is a matter of calling `.name` on any of the returned objects:

```
for child in children:
    print child.name
```